# .replace() randomly not replacing string correctly

Tags: python

I am using .rsplit() to split up all the digits in a string after the last comma using further commas. The transformations should be like this:

Before:

```
,000
```

After:

```
,0,0,0
```

I am using the following method to do this:

```
upl = line.rsplit(",",1)[1:]
upl2 = "{}".format(",".join(list(upl[0])))
```

As a comparison, to ensure that the correct substring is being selected to begin with, I am also using this statement:

```
upl1 = "{}".format("".join(list(upl[0])))
```

I then print both to ensure that they are both as expected. In this example I get:

```
up1 = ,000
up2 = ,0,0,0,
```

I then use a .replace() statement to substitute out my before substring with my after one:

```
new_var = ''
            for line in new_var.split("\n"):
                upl = line.rsplit(",",1)[1:]
                upl1 = "{}".format("".join(list(upl[0])))
                upl2 = "{}".format(",".join(list(upl[0])))
                upl2 = str(upl2)
                upl1 = str(upl1)
                new_var += line.replace(upl1, upl2) + '\n'
```

In almost all instances of parsed data the old substring is overwritten with the new correctly. However on a few the subbed in string will display as:

```
,0,00 when it should be ,0,0,0,
```

Can anyone see anything obvious as to why this might be as I am at a bit of a loss.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Here is the Scrapy code I am using to generate the data I am manipulating. The issues come from line:

```
new_match3g += line.replace(spl1, spl2).replace(tpl1, tpl2).replace(upl1, upl2) + '\n'
```

The full code is:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags
import time
import re
import json


class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mrcrawl2"
    allowed_domains = ["whoscored.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.whoscored.com"]
    download_delay = 5

    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('/Seasons'),deny=('/News', '/Fixtures', '/Graphics', '/Articles', '/Live', '/Matches', '/Explanations', '/Glossary', '/Players', 'ContactUs', 'TermsOfUse', 'Jobs', 'AboutUs', 'RSS'),), follow=False, callback='parse_item')]

    def parse_item(self, response):

        sel = Selector(response)

        regex = re.compile('DataStore\.prime\(\'history\', { stageId: \d+ },\[\[.*?\]\]?\)?;', re.S)

        match2g = re.search(regex, response.body)

        if match2g is not None:
            match3g = match2g.group()

            match3g = str(match3g)
            match3g = match3g.replace("'", '').replace("'", '').replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace('] );', '') 

            match3g = re.sub("DataStore\.prime\(history, { stageId: \d+ },", '', match3g)
            match3g = match3g.replace(');', '')
            #print'-' * 170, '\n', match3g.decode('utf-8'), '-' * 170, '\n'

            new_match3g = ''
            for line in match3g.split("\n"):
                upl = line.rsplit(",",1)[1:]
                if upl:
                    upl1 = "{}".format("".join(list(upl[0])))
                    upl2 = "{}".format(",".join(list(upl[0])))
                    upl2 = str(upl2)
                    upl1 = str(upl1)
                    new_match3g += line.replace(upl1, upl2) + '\n'

                    print "UPL1 = ", upl1
                    print "UPL2 = ", upl2

            print'-' * 170, '\n', new_match3g.decode('utf-8'), '-' * 170, '\n'
            print'-' * 170, '\n', match3g.decode('utf-8'), '-' * 170, '\n'



execute(['scrapy','crawl','mrcrawl2'])
```

Comment: Just as with [your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25495270/using-rsplit-not-giving-desired-results), you have a bunch of steps that don't do anything at all. In fact, now you have even more than before. What is the `"{}".format(…)` intended to do? What is the `upl2 = str(upl2)` intended to do? If you can't answer those questions, and explain what each line of code is supposed to do, how are you going to understand what one of those lines is doing wrong?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: What is `list(line)[1:]` supposed to do? What does converting from one kind of iterable to another do for you here?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Of course not, but why use `list` for absolutely no reason whatsoever instead?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham im using the string format because the larger string that i am substituting one substring for another within is already in str() format, so i thought i would need to use str().

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it isnt the adding commas to the string that is not working, it is the subbing that string back into the main string that works most of the time, but then in some instances does not. i can post the full scrapy code if you wish and you can see for yourself.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: `join` doesn't require a list, it takes any iterable. A string is already an iterable. Converting it to a list doesn't add anything.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham please see edited question. i hope this makes the issue clearer for you both.

Comment: @user3045351: Your edited question, which repeats the multiple unnecessary steps 6 times instead of 2 times, doesn't make it any clearer why you've included those unnecessary steps. Again, what is each line of your code supposed to be doing?

Comment: @abarnert 1) take each line of the string 'match3g' and split at at the points described with the variables 'spl', 'upl', 'tpl'...then break those strings up using commas. these are defined as 'spl2', 'upl2', 'tpl2'. 2) i have specified variables 'spl1' etc that are the same as 'spl' just so i could see them more clearly, but they are not actually required. these represent the string before the commas were added. 3) the line 'new_match3g += line.replace(spl1, spl2).replace(tpl1, tpl2).replace(upl1, upl2) + '\n'' is replacing old with new for every line of the string 'match3g being parsed...

Comment: ...and generating a new string called 'new_match3g' with the new, comma separated substrings subbed in.

Comment: First, don't leave your question incomprehensible and try to explain it in comments, edit it so that it has an MCVE with an explanation that makes sense. Second, what do you think `"{}".format(s)` or `str(s)` are doing to your strings that's useful? If nothing, why did you write them? If something, then there's your problem: they don't do whatever it was that you expected. That's why I'm asking you to go through each step one by one and explain it, because it's not clear what they're supposed to be doing, and therefore it's not clear where you're going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've given us an example, let's trace it through:

```
>>> line = ',9243,46,Unterhaching,2,11333,8,13,1,133'
>>> split = line.rsplit(",",1)
>>> split
[',9243,46,Unterhaching,2,11333,8,13,1', '133']
>>> upl = split[1:]
>>> upl
['133']
>>> upl0 = upl[0]
>>> upl0
'133'
>>> upl0_list = list(upl0)
>>> upl0_list
['1', '3', '3']
>>> joined1 = "".join(upl0_list)
>>> joined1
'133'
>>> upl1 = "{}".format(joined1)
>>> upl1
'133'
>>> joined2 = ",".join(upl0_list)
>>> joined2
'1,3,3'
>>> upl2 = "{}".format(joined2)
>>> upl2
'1,3,3'
>>> upl2 = str(upl2)
>>> upl2
'1,3,3'
>>> upl1 = str(upl1)
>>> upl1
'133'
>>> r = line.replace(upl1, upl2)
>>> r
',9243,46,Unterhaching,2,11,3,33,8,13,1,1,3,3'
```

Again, notice that more than half of the steps don't actually do anything at all. You're converting strings to the same strings, then converting them to the same strings again; you're converting them to lists just to join them back together; etc. If you can't explain what each step is supposed to do, why are you doing them? Your code is supposed to be instructions to the computer to do something; just giving it random instructions that you don't understand isn't going to do any good.

More importantly, that's not the output you described. It has a *different* problem than the one you described: in addition to correctly replacing the `133` at the end with `1,3,3`, it's *also* replacing the embedded `133` in the middle of `11333` with `11,3,33`. Because that's exactly what you're asking it to do.

So, assuming that's your actual problem, rather than the problem you asked about, how do you fix that?

Well, you don't. You don't want to replace every `'133'` substring with `'1,3,3'`, so don't ask it to do that. You want to make a string with everything up to the last comma, followed by the processed version of everything after the last comma. In other words:

```
>>> ",".join([split[0], upl2])
',9243,46,Unterhaching,2,11333,8,13,1,1,3,3'
```

Comment: yes it is...because i am using multiple replace statements in my full code. i'm going to edit my original question to show the scrapy code i am using to generate the data i am then manipulating.

Comment: @user3045351: If that's what you're actually seeing, then the example code you've given us isn't a good example, because it doesn't demonstrate your problem. Giving us all of your code isn't going to help. You need to give us a simple example that does just enough to demonstrate your problem—but that actually does demonstrate your problem. Please read [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if this isn't clear.

Comment: see edited question above. without you running that code block through yourself we aren't going to get anywhere as i dont think the minimal approach to my question is really conveying the issue properly. thanks

Comment: @user3045351 If your minimal example doesn't convey what the problem is, you may want to spend some time thinking about how to come up with one that does. You might find that *you* end up with a better idea of exactly what you want to do, which is a bit unclear at the moment.

Comment: @marius i know what i want to do. im taking particular substrings from within a larger string and separating each byte with a comma. i am then generating a new string that replaces the old substrings with the new. the method extracting and comma separating substrings works fine, however for some reason when i am generating a new string it is not writing out this new comma separated substring correctly. thanks

Comment: @user3045351: My answer explains exactly why `str.replace` isn't doing what you want. You're asking it to replace every `'133'` substring with `'1,3,3'`, even though there are other `'133'` substrings in your string that you don't want to replace. Is that not clear to you?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
>>> ",000".replace("", ",")[2:]
',0,0,0,'
```

Comment: thanks for replying. it isn't that the substring is being converted correctly initially, it is that the corrected substring is not being written back into the larger string in all instances correctly. thanks

Comment: Do you have some further samples of where it is an isn't working? Is the string the same in both cases?

Comment: an example of a before and after line not converted correctly is before: ',9243,46,Unterhaching,2,11333,8,13,1,133' and after:',9243,46,Unterhaching,2,1,1,3,3,3,8,1,3,1,1,33'...the last three digits should read as ',1,3,3'...the conversion process itself appears to work, its the subbing it back in again that does not in all instances. thanks